# Not able to connect to spark thrift server via jdbc driver in play framework with anorm

Tags: jdbc, hive, playframework, anorm, spark-thriftserver

I am trying to connect my spark thrift server using play framework via [anorm](http://playframework.github.io/anorm/).

- Play framework version - 2.8.18
- Connecting to jdbc as explained [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/AccessingAnSQLDatabase)
- Anorm - 2.7.0
- Spark thrift server version - spark 3.2.1, Hadoop 3.2
- Scala - 2.13.5

Jdbc driver & dependencies I have

- [hive-jdbc](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-jdbc/3.1.3)

Exception I am getting as response when I hit url

```
"java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method not supported",
                "at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveResultSetMetaData.getTableName(HiveResultSetMetaData.java:102)",
                "at anorm.MetaData$.tableName$1(MetaData.scala:148)",
                "at anorm.MetaData$.$anonfun$parse$1(MetaData.scala:153)",
                "at anorm.MetaData$.$anonfun$parse$1$adapted(MetaData.scala:139)",
                "at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:246)",
                "at anorm.MetaData$.parse(MetaData.scala:139)",
                "at anorm.Cursor$.apply(Cursor.scala:27)",
                "at anorm.Sql$.unsafeCursor(Anorm.scala:250)",
                "at anorm.Sql$.$anonfun$withResult$1(Anorm.scala:256)",
                "at scala.Function1.$anonfun$andThen$1(Function1.scala:85)",
                "at resource.AbstractManagedResource.$anonfun$acquireFor$1(AbstractManagedResource.scala:85)",
                "at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.$anonfun$either$1(Exception.scala:251)",
                "at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:227)",
                "at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.either(Exception.scala:251)",
                "at resource.AbstractManagedResource.acquireFor(AbstractManagedResource.scala:85)",
                "at resource.ManagedResourceOperations$$anon$1.$anonfun$acquireFor$1(ManagedResourceOperations.scala:47)",
                "at resource.AbstractManagedResource.$anonfun$acquireFor$1(AbstractManagedResource.scala:85)",
                "at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.$anonfun$either$1(Exception.scala:251)",
                "at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:227)",
                "at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.either(Exception.scala:251)",
                "at resource.AbstractManagedResource.acquireFor(AbstractManagedResource.scala:85)",
                "at resource.ManagedResourceOperations$$anon$1.acquireFor(ManagedResourceOperations.scala:47)",
                "at resource.DeferredExtractableManagedResource.acquireFor(AbstractManagedResource.scala:25)",
                "at resource.ManagedResourceOperations.apply(ManagedResourceOperations.scala:31)",
                "at resource.ManagedResourceOperations.apply$(ManagedResourceOperations.scala:31)",
                "at resource.DeferredExtractableManagedResource.apply(AbstractManagedResource.scala:22)",
                "at resource.ManagedResourceOperations.acquireAndGet(ManagedResourceOperations.scala:29)",
                "at resource.ManagedResourceOperations.acquireAndGet$(ManagedResourceOperations.scala:29)",
                "at resource.DeferredExtractableManagedResource.acquireAndGet(AbstractManagedResource.scala:22)",
                "at anorm.Sql$.$anonfun$asTry$1(Anorm.scala:263)",
                "at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:210)",
                "at anorm.Sql$.asTry(Anorm.scala:263)",
                "at anorm.WithResult.asTry(SqlResult.scala:215)",
                "at anorm.WithResult.asTry$(SqlResult.scala:213)",
                "at anorm.SimpleSql.asTry(SimpleSql.scala:6)",
                "at anorm.WithResult.as(SqlResult.scala:205)",
                "at anorm.WithResult.as$(SqlResult.scala:204)",
                "at anorm.SimpleSql.as(SimpleSql.scala:6)",
                "at v2.thrift.ThriftQueryServiceImpl.$anonfun$getDataV2$5(ThriftQueryServiceImpl.scala:33)",
                "at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:246)",
                "at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:79)",
                "at v2.thrift.ThriftQueryServiceImpl.$anonfun$getDataV2$4(ThriftQueryServiceImpl.scala:32)",
                "at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.withConnection(Databases.scala:180)",
                "at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.withConnection(Databases.scala:174)",
                "at v2.thrift.ThriftQueryServiceImpl.$anonfun$getDataV2$3(ThriftQueryServiceImpl.scala:31)",
                "at play.api.cache.redis.RecoverWithDefault.recoverFrom(RecoveryPolicy.scala:111)",
                "at play.api.cache.redis.RecoverWithDefault.recoverFrom$(RecoveryPolicy.scala:109)",
                "at play.api.cache.redis.LogAndDefaultPolicy.play$api$cache$redis$Reports$$super$recoverFrom(RecoveryPolicy.scala:125)",
                "at play.api.cache.redis.Reports.recoverFrom(RecoveryPolicy.scala:70)",
                "at play.api.cache.redis.Reports.recoverFrom$(RecoveryPolicy.scala:66)",
                "at play.api.cache.redis.LogAndDefaultPolicy.recoverFrom(RecoveryPolicy.scala:125)",
                "at play.api.cache.redis.impl.dsl$RecoveryFuture$$anonfun$recoverWithFuture$1.applyOrElse(dsl.scala:33)",
                "at play.api.cache.redis.impl.dsl$RecoveryFuture$$anonfun$recoverWithFuture$1.applyOrElse(dsl.scala:31)",
                "at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.run(Promise.scala:454)",
                "at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)",
                "at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)",
                "at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)",
                "at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:94)",
                "at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)",
                "at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:49)",
                "at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:48)",
                "at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)",
                "at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)",
                "at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)",
                "at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)",
                "at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)"
```

Seems like anorm is calling function HiveResultSetMetaData.getTableName. When I checked this in hive jdbc driver [source code](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/jdbc/src/java/org/apache/hive/jdbc/HiveResultSetMetaData.java#L101) it is not implemented and throws an exception.

I am able to connect to thrift server properly from a plain Java class below with above dependency.

```
package org.example;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class HiveJDBCConnect {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection con = null;
    try {

        String conStr = "jdbc:hive2://spark-thrift:10000/test_schema;auth=noSasl";
        Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(conStr, "root", "root");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select key2 from ir_test");
        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.print(rs.getString(1));
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("show database successfully.");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (con != null)
                con.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}}
```

I tried with the following driver as well with no luck.

- [spark-project-hive-jdbc](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.spark-project.hive/hive-jdbc/1.2.1.spark) - This one even connection is not getting due to the issue mentioned [here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/747) from connection pool I am using.

How can I resolve this ? Is there any driver out there which can connect to spark thrift server which has these method defined ?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Hive JDBC driver doesn't support that and many other methods. You should try using the [Cloudera Hive JDBC Driver](https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/connectors/hive/jdbc/2-6-21.html). Unfortunately, I don't think it's available in Maven.